# How to retrieve OpenWeatherMap data using JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, openweathermap

I've been trying to write a program in JavaScript that can retrieve weather data from OpenWeatherMap using JSON. I'm pretty new to JSON, but I think that I understand the logic behind it. However, when I click the "Get JSON" button, nothing happens. It's possible that "data.temp" in the getJSON function is incorrect, but if I'm understanding correctly, it seems like it should at least print the word "Temperature:" HTML and JavaScript are enclosed below, any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>  

<div id = "owmData" style = "background-color:#cc0;">
     Weather data should go here.
  </div>
```

Get JSON

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Operate when "getIt" button is clicked.*/
$("#getIt").click(function(event){      

 /* Variable storing weather information.*/
 var weatherNow="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&callback=test&appid=******************";

 $.getJSON(weatherNow,function(data){         
                    $('#owmdata').append('<p>Temperature : ' + data.temp+ '</p>');


});
 });
 });
```

Comment: You probably want to obfuscate your AppId from users here. Just a thought. Anyone can now use this appid to call the API.

Answer (score 1):

In your request parameters you are specifying "test" as the callback function. You can strucuture your request url like this without the ref to the callback and access the data directly:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=*************
```

"temp" is nested inside of the property "main" so you would reference it as `data.main.temp`

Comment: Thanks, the main culprits were this along with a capitalization error.